# What is a compact 2-dimensional surface without boundary?

Tags: general-topology

When I am reading the descriptions of 2-dimensional Poincare conjecture on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture#:%7E:text=A%20compact%202%2Ddimensional%20surface,true%20for%203%2Ddimensional%20spaces.) , it menstions "a compact 2-dimensional surface without boundary". People told me that a 2-sphere will be an example of "a compact 2-dimensional surface without boundary". My question is, what is the topological space we are talking about? Is it $\mathbb R^3$  or the 2-sphere itself?

If the whole topological space is $\mathbb R^3$, then a 2-sphere is clearly bounded. It is closed because $\mathbb R^3 \backslash \{(x, y, z) \vert x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$ is open. But in this case the 2-sphere contains the boundary, because the interior of a 2-sphere will be empty, and the closure will be 2-sphere itself. Hency the boundary will be 2-sphere itself.

If the whole topological space is the 2-sphere itself, then it is also bounded. It is closed because the empty set is open. Hence it is compact. The interior is 2-sphere itself, and the closure is also 2-sphere. So it is without a boundary.

So looks like we are using the 2-sphere as the whole topological space. Is my understanding correct?

To summarize my question, what will be the whole topological space in the context of the 2-dimensional Poincare conjecture?

Comment: There are two notions of boundary in topology. The one used in Wikipedia is different from the one you are using in the question.

Comment: Is the "boundary" used in Wikipedia [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)). Am I not describing the same "boundary"?

Comment: Yes, it is different. Read about [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary).

Comment: But the end of the first paragraph inside your link points to [my previous link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)), which is the same "boundary". Would you elaborate more on what the "boundary" here is? Isn't it "closure - interior"?

Comment: So what? Sometimes the two notions coincide. Read the article I linked and see if you understand the relevant definition.

Comment: Boundaries have boundary points. A boundary point is a point such that every open neighborhood of that point contains points inside and outside of the set. Two dimensional neighborhoods on the surface of the sphere only contain points on that surface. You need a three dimensional neighborhood to get points outside the sphere but that is a property of the embedding, not the two sphere itself.

Comment: @CyclotomicField thanks, I understand what you said, but I do not understand what Moishe said. What are the "two notions of topology"? Aren't we all using the same definitions, i.e., "Closure - Interior"?

Comment: Let me repeat: Boundary in the sense of "topology of manifolds" **is not** "closure minus the interior." Read the Wikipedia article to understand the proper definition. But first, you have to understand what a *manifold* is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistaken, the two sphere does not contain a boundary because every point is an interior point. This mean it has no boundary points. Note that the two sphere is merely the surface of a sphere, no other points are included. The interior and exterior you're describing are part of $\mathbb{R}^3$ not the two sphere.